# List all surveys programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to change some permissions for all surveys in a SharePoint 2010 site collection, how can I list them?

For example to list document libraries  I can do

```
            SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
            foreach (SPWeb web in collWebsite)
            {
        SPListCollection collList = web.Lists;

                foreach (SPList oList in collList)
        {
                if (oList is SPDocumentLibrary)
                {
                   // Do something
                }
        }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your if statement use

```
if (oList.BaseType == SPBaseType.Survey)
```